# Why is my if/else...if statement not working?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

One picture gets displayed, and you get to click a button. If the buttons class matches the class of the picture (i.e. you're correct) - I want to print a message. And I am.

But if the classes do not match I wish to display a message saying that the guess was wrong. It's easier shown. So here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.left').hide();
$('.right').hide();

$('.happy').click(function(){

    $('.left').show();
    $('.right').show();

    if($(this).hasClass('happy') && $("img").hasClass('happy')){
        $('h2').replaceWith("<h2>You are correct!</h2>");
    }else if(!$('img').hasClass('happy')){
    alert("LOL");
    };
});
});
```

The first part of my code, that displays the h2 if the button has been pressed - works. But the second part - else if(**!**$('img').hasClass('happy')) - does not. Why?

My HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/WEAt6/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>
       gzzzz
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="answers">
        <div class="sadness">
            <p class="feelings">SADNESS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="anger">
            <p class="feelings">ANGER</p>
        </div>
        <div class="surprise">
            <p class="feelings">SURPRISE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fear">
            <p class="feelings">FEAR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="disgust">
            <p class="feelings">DISGUST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contempt">
            <p class="feelings">CONTEMPT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="happy">
            <p class="feelings">HAPPINESS</p>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="thegame">
            <div class="pic">
                <img class="left" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Happy_man.jpg"/ >
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <img class="happy" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Happy_man.jpg"/ >
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <img class="right" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Happy_man.jpg"/ >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="score">
            <h2></h2>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="stuff.js"></script>
</html>
​
```

Comment: $("img") selects all the images in dom. Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri here's the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/WEAt6/

Comment: @Chandu I have posted my HTML.

Comment: @Sweely: Always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. (Links to live sites like jsFiddle are a nice thing to do *as well*, but not *instead*.) I've done it for you this time, but c'mon, this is your 10th question, you should understand how the site works by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic of your `if` statement has **two** conditions. So it's possible that `$(this).hasClass('happy')` is false, but `$("img").hasClass('happy')` (in the `else if`) is true, so neither the `if` block nor the `else if` block's code runs.

A couple of side-notes:

1. `$("img").hasClass('happy')` will tell you whether **any** `img` in the document has the class `happy`. <s>You haven't quoted your HTML, but it seems worth mentioning.</s> So since you do have an image with that class, it will always be true. If you want to check a specific image, either give it a second class and use `$("img.theOtherClass").hasClass("happy")` or you can do it by position: `$("img").first().hasClass("happy")` for the first, `$("img").eq(1).hasClass('happy')` for the second (`eq` is 0-based), etc.
2. `$('h2').replaceWith("<h2>You are correct!</h2>");` replaces the `h2` with another, new `h2`. Probably better just to change its *content*: `$('h2').html('You are correct!');`.
3. The code in #2 above (both yours and mine) will change **all** `h2` elements in the document. Again, maybe that's fine, but it seemed worth highlighting. You might consider `$("#score h2").html("You are correct!");` if you just want to change the one inside the element with the `id` `"score"`.

Comment: The if block's code runs just fine. If both the conditions are true - it runs. And it currently does. My second if block does not...

Comment: @Sweely: Right. Again, it's perfectly possible for neither the condition in the `if` nor the condition in the `else if` to be true. That would happen if `$(this).hasClass('happy')` is false but `$("img").hasClass('happy')` is true, **neither** block would run.

Comment: T.J. - you're on to something. If I select the *first* >img< with this code $("img").hasClass('happy') - how do I select the second? Please check my HTML if you've got the time.

Comment: @Sweely: Now that you've posted your HTML: The condition `$("img").hasClass('happy')` will always be true given your markup, becaase you have an `img` that has the class. See point #1 above (now corrected).

Comment: @Sweely: The answer was wrong, `hasClass` will be true if *any* `img` has the class, not the first one. (My mistake, corrected above.) If you want to know if the **first** image on the page has the class, do `$("img").first().hasClass('happy')`. For the second, `$("img").eq(1).hasClass('happy')` (`eq` is 0-based), etc.

Comment: Okay. So I wish to check *if the second picture in my div.thegame has the given class* - that's gonna solve my problem T.J. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21007/discussion-between-sweely-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: @Sweely: I don't do the chat thing if it's relevant to the question or answer. It's one of the stupidest things about SO. If you have a further question, ask it here, although I think I've pointed you at how to check the second img.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an `else if`? Surely you are checking whether is has the class, or not. There is no need to do a second comparison. Just use `else`

```
if($(this).hasClass('happy') && $("img").hasClass('happy')){
    $('h2').replaceWith("<h2>You are correct!</h2>");
}else {
    alert("LOL");
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it simply does not work. Take a look at my HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/WEAt6/

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the log see the demo please:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WEAt6/5/)

```
$('#answers div').click(function(){

        $('.left').show();
        $('.right').show();

        if($(this).hasClass('happy') && $("img").hasClass('happy')){

            $('h2').replaceWith("<h2>You are correct! Happiness looks the same on everybody.</h2>");
            setTimeout(trolli,2000);
            function trolli(){

             sadgame = $('.thegame').html('<div class="pic"><img class="left" src="http://f1.pepst.com/c/01850B/322662/ssc3/home/062/dard-sms/sad_wom_an.jpg_480_480_0_64000_0_1_0.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="sadness" src="http://f1.pepst.com/c/01850B/322662/ssc3/home/062/dard-sms/sad_wom_an.jpg_480_480_0_64000_0_1_0.jpg"/ ></div><div class="pic"><img class="right" src="http://f1.pepst.com/c/01850B/322662/ssc3/home/062/dard-sms/sad_wom_an.jpg_480_480_0_64000_0_1_0.jpg"/ ></div>');
            $('h2').replaceWith("<h2>What emotion is being shown?</h2>");
            $('.left').hide();
            $('.right').hide();

            }

        }else if(!$(this).hasClass('happy')){
            alert("LOL");
        };
    });
```